# moment.js - Use strictness on short form of month in French

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using a jquery plugin that requires moment.js, and because I'm quite new to it's confusing me.

Based on the moment.js/doc and some other threads that I found online, I understand the following:

(From http://momentjs.com/docs/)

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired
>   behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last
>   argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires
>   that the format and input match exactly.

```
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();        // true
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();  // false
moment('2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();        // true
```

We can also use both language and strictness:

```
moment('2012-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'fr', true);
```

When I tried to use French Locale,  moment('2012-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'fr-ca', true) didn't return true. (BTW, 'fr-ca' is Canadian French Locale if you are wondering.)

```
    var date = '1 févr. 2017'; // it means 1 Feb. 2017
    var format ='D MMM YYYY'; 

    var locale = 'fr-ca';

    moment.locale(locale);

// Problem starts here:
   moment(date, format, locale).isValid(); // return true as expected.
   moment(date, format, locale, true).isValid(); // return false, not expected.
```

What I can think of is that probably "févr." is not format of "MMM". If not, what can it be?

Here is a list of short-form Month names in French from moment-locale.js source code.

```
monthsShort : 'janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.'
```

Below is the full version of what I tried, please help me identify what I did wrong.

> https://jsfiddle.net/egcwzk2u/2/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period (`.`) in the abbreviation is ignored when using the default flexible parsing, but in strict mode the string must match the format *exactly*, and it doesn't because of the period.

There are two options:

1. You can remove the period from the input string.

   ```
   var date = '1 févr 2017';
   var format ='D MMM YYYY';
   ```
2. Or, you can change the format to allow the period:

   ```
   var date = '1 févr. 2017';
   var format ='D MMM. YYYY';
   ```